# GTK for C in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, gtk

My setup: MacOS 10.15.2, Xcode 11.3
Please help me to install gtk for C in Xcode
I've already tried but always get "file not found"
On their website there is an information about installation: they offer to use an installation file but link for it doesn't work and it can't help with installation to Xcode
What should I do?

Comment: Have you considered to try [CodeBlocks](http://codeblocks.org). [Take a Look also here, it is about LinuxMint but you can make you an idea.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVpC2HcWuWqMiVbAlzHdl8TM). There are lots of GTK3 Tutorials as well.

Comment: Hi! Take a look at homebrew: https://brew.sh/ https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gtk+3